# Names of certain sites are cut off in the sites page icons

Tags: bug, design, stack-exchange, fonts

In the [sites page](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=grid) (grid view), the names of **Software Quality Assurance & Testing** and **ExpressionEngine® Answers** in the icons are cut off.

These sites have less users, questions and traffic when compared to certain other sites, so they have smaller icons. Can the font size be adjusted (or any other possible method) so that their full names are visible?

[image]

Comment: Can reproduce in Firefox 90.0a1